# Does "more or less" mean "almost"?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I checked out its meaning on the web and the common one I have found is "speaking imprecisely", but instinctively I thought it would be like "almost", for example:

> The task assigned is more or less over, only formatting is left to be done.

Comment: That's close enough.

Comment: [more or less](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/more?q=more+or+less#more__15)

Comment: Please read our [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/writing-good-meaning-questions/) about how to write good [tag:meaning] questions.

Comment: Logically, we shouldn't use it to mean _almost_ as that negates the 'more' possibility - but we do.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I see no reason to look at it that way. An expanded form might be *[a small amount] more or less*, in just the same way as *give or take [a small amount]*. I often hear/use *plus or minus* used in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it translates to *roughly*, *around*, or *about* a little better than *almost*. (When used for numerical estimates, *roughly* implies the number could be off by a little bit in either direction; while *almost* sometimes implies that, if the number is off, it's probably too low, rather than too high.)

Another relatively common way to say it is *give or take*:

> *I ran about 7 kilometers yesterday, give or take.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes. According to [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/more+or+less), which says that the definition is "approximately".

Synonyms are:

> about, **almost**, around, ballpark figure, bordering on, circa, close to,
>   in the ballpark, in the neighborhood of, in the vicinity of, just
>   about, not far from, not quite, on average, relatively, roughly,
>   thereabouts, very close

Answer (score 1):

More or Less :)

They both refer to an approximation, but "almost" would serve better when something was not quite meeting a criterion (*I almost made the bus, but had to walk home instead*), while "more or less" serves better when something meets a criterion well enough that we can consider it to have done so (*After trick-and-treating, we shared the sweets more or less equally*).

Comment: you know what I am a huge fan of recursion, this is going down as one of the examples :)